# How to handle R values in libraries

Tags: android

I would like to make multiple android apps that are nearly identical so I created a library.

However I have run into a problem because each library project creates its own R class.

Each application has a slightly different layout, but most of the code modifying text and images in the layout is the same, therefore I want it in the library.

However then I can't access the layout variables in the application R class.

Comment: for example, if I want to make several video poker games, the code is mostly identical.  the layouts are very similar (same images, same text, same code for button clicks), but each application needs its own layout since the pay tables may be different and the title is different.

Answer (score 0):

My library project is a complete valid project just marked as a library one. As I need to change some icons and some strings, I just "override" them in the library project by providing the new images with the same name in the drawable folder and my strings.xml contains only the changed strings.

So if you want to change a layout, just copy it from the library project and modify it a bit. It will override the library layout automatically.

To understand this you just need to understand how a library project works: It is not compiled and included, it is included before compiling so your modifications will override the project stuff.